# Need help solving memory leak error

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

When I run valgrind, I get one error at method insert for operator new;
I know this probably means that I have to delete node n how I tried so many things to try to delete it but it just gives me even more errors. Please hel.

```
class key_value_sequences {
public:

    struct node{
      int key;
      vector<int> values;
      node* next;
      node* prev;
    };

    key_value_sequences() {
    }
    ~key_value_sequences() {
    }
    key_value_sequences(const key_value_sequences& A) {
      n = A.n;
      head = A.head;
      tail = A.tail;
      v = A.v;
    }
    key_value_sequences& operator=(const key_value_sequences& A) {
      if (this == &A) return *this;
      n = A.n;
      head = A.head;
      tail = A.tail;
      v = A.v;
      return *this;
    }
    // YOU SHOULD USE C++ CONTAINERS TO AVOID RAW POINTERS
    // IF YOU DECIDE TO USE POINTERS, MAKE SURE THAT YOU MANAGE MEMORY PROPERLY

    // IMPLEMENT ME: SHOULD RETURN SIZE OF A SEQUENCE FOR GIVEN KEY
    // IF NO SEQUENCE EXISTS FOR A GIVEN KEY RETURN -1
    int size(int key) const {
      if (find(v.begin(), v.end(), key)!=v.end()) {
        node* temp = head;
        while(temp != NULL) {
          if (temp->key == key) {
            return temp->values.size();
          }
          else temp = temp->next;
      }
    }
      else return -1;
  }

    // IMPLEMENT ME: SHOULD RETURN POINTER TO A SEQUENCE FOR GIVEN KEY
    // IF NO SEQUENCE EXISTS FOR A GIVEN KEY RETURN nullptr
    const int* data(int key) const {
      if (find(v.begin(), v.end(), key)!=v.end()) {
        node* temp = head;
        while(temp != NULL) {
          if (temp->key == key) {
            return temp->values.data();
          }
          else temp = temp->next;
      }
    }
      else return nullptr;
  }

    // IMPLEMENT ME: INSERT VALUE INTO A SEQUENCE IDENTIFIED BY GIVEN KEY
    void insert(int key, int value) {
      if(v.size() == 0) { //empty list
        v.push_back(key);
        n = new node;
        n->prev = NULL;
        n->key = key;
        n->values.push_back(value);
        head = n;
        tail = n;
      }
      else if((find(v.begin(), v.end(), key)!=v.end())) { //if key exists already
        node* temp = head;
        while(temp != NULL) {
          if (temp->key == key) {
            temp->values.push_back(value);
            break;
          }
          else temp = temp->next;
        }
      }
      else { //if theres no existing key
        v.push_back(key);
        n = new node;
        n->key = key;
        n->values.push_back(value);
        n->prev = tail;
        tail->next = n;
        tail = n;
        tail->next = NULL;
      }
    }
private:
    vector<int> v;
    node* n;
    node* head;
    node* tail;
}; // class key_value_sequences

#endif // A3_HPP
```

Comment: The code of your copy constructor, your destructor and your `operator=` is not consistent with the `insert` method. The destructor should delete the node in sequence. The copy constructor and the `operator=` should perform a deep copy of the list, not share the nodes.

Comment: *"YOU SHOULD USE C++ CONTAINERS TO AVOID RAW POINTERS"* - Good advice. Why not follow it?

Answer (score 0):

In `insert` method:

```
  if(v.size() == 0) { //empty list
    v.push_back(key);
    n = new node;
    n->prev = NULL;
    n->key = key;
    n->values.push_back(value);
    head = n;
    tail = n;
  }
```

You are not setting the `head->next` to NULL. I suspect that could be the problem while inserting second value.

```
  while(temp != NULL) {  //  <<<<< Is temp uninitialized?
      if (temp->key == key) {
        temp->values.push_back(value);
        break;
      }
      else temp = temp->next;
```

Its pretty dangerous to not initialize the pointer to NULL

Comment: also, you missed a line of code that i wrote above the while loop.